# solve this style problem for IE6 and IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

First i will show you the problem, wich only happens on IE6/IE7

[image]

As you can see, when the length of the innerHtml it's not long, no problem; but when it's 'longer' the sprite set as bg image gets repeated and the text jumps to the next line...

now, the CSS

```
.contButton {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}


.contButton p {
    float: left;
    display: inline; /*For ignore double margin in IE6*/
    margin: 0 0 0 10px !important;
}
.contButton a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
.contButton span {
    margin: 0px 10px 0 -10px;
    padding: 3px 8px 5px 18px;
    position: relative; /*To fix IE6 problem (not displaying)*/
    float:left;
}
/*ESTADO NORMAL AZUL*/
.contButton p a {
    background: url(../nImg/spriteBotones.png) no-repeat right -214px;
    _background: url(../nImg/spriteBotones.gif) no-repeat right -214px;
    color: #FFF;    
}


.contButton p a span {
    background: url(../nImg/spriteBotones.png) no-repeat left -214px;
    _background: url(../nImg/spriteBotones.gif) no-repeat left -214px;
}
```

And the Html:

```
<div class="">
....
<div class="contButton mt10">
   <p><a tabindex="" title="acceder" href="#"><span>ver disponibilidad</span></a></p>
</div> 
...
</div>
```

This is the bg Image.
![the sprite][2]

Tried with:

```
<!--[if IE lte 7]>



<style type="text/css"> 
/*
.contNombrePrecioHtl .contButton p a{ height:20px;  }
.contNombrePrecioHtl .contButton p a span{ height:20px; width:auto; }  */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

But that didn't solve the problem...

PS: class="mt10" it's only a `margin-top:10px;`

Any idea how to solve this for the glorious IE6/7?

Comment: IE7 should support max-width, so you can set the proper (you have to find out what it is) maximum width and it will never be two lines. not sure though how to deal with IE6

Comment: So what *should* happen? The text should always stay on one line no matter how long it is?

Comment: the sprite should repeat a bit more, text in same line; if you realise, the <span> has the left bg, and the <a> has the right bg...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap` to `.contButton`.

Comment: This way i see it perfect in IE, but the right rounded corner dissapears in FF; Do I have to apply it as a hack??

Comment: You can use `*white-space: nowrap` to apply it only in IE7 and lower.

Comment: f I set it to .contButton it works in both; what do you think?? (if i can solve it with no hacks better)

Comment: If it works in all browsers on `.contButton`, then sure, just set it on that. Remember, I can't see what you're looking at - I'm just "guessing".

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
.contButton span {
  margin: 0px 10px 0 -10px;
  padding: 3px 8px 5px 18px;
  position: relative; /*To fix IE6 problem (not displaying)*/
  float:left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This way i see it perfect in IE, but the right rounded corner dissapears in FF; Do I have to apply it as a hack??

Comment: if I set it to .contButton it works in both; what do you think??

Answer (score 0):

1. can you try to add overflow: hidden to each parent of element with float: left? in this case you will have to add it to each div, p and a. I am not sure whether your actual code is optimal.
2. Moreover, float: left; and display: inline together make no sense. This might be the reason of the strange behaviour. Delete display: inline (remember about adding overflow: hidden to its parent) and it should work. 
   Haven't tested though.

UPDATE:

apparently as the author of the question mentions float:left + display: inline fixes IE6 double margin bug for floating elements.

Comment: `float:left; display:inline` purely [fixes an IE6 bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a problem with either IE versions, it's probably just the newer browsers being less strict about this particular thing. I haven't tested anything, but "display:inline-block" has helped me sometimes. Still it doesn't seem like the most effective solution. The width seems to be limiting here, you shouldn't give the thing a fixed width if you don't want the text to "jump" into a second line...

Comment: forget my comment on fixed width, there's no fixed with in your code.. :P

Answer (score -1):

defining dimensions for elements like `p` oder `span` is always somewhere between *tricky* and *impossible*, because they are inline elements. I'd recommend modifying the surrounding block element div.contButton.

In addition to height you should set overflow to hidden:

```
.contButton { 
    height:20px; 
    width:219px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i cannot set so much width, because sometimes the texts is 'shorter', for example :(

Comment: by the way you can hack styles that you'd like to apply in IE only like that:

`*  html div.contButton { /* IE-only-Formatting */ }`

Comment: -1: p is not inline element! check [proof on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLB3P/) if you need

Comment: I did just take the 219px from your (previous) example... 
you can leave width at "auto". With `overflow:hidden` on the parent DIV the `P` and `A`might become higher than the DIV, but the DIV will not be expanded. Content will be cut off at 20px height.